# Calculating ratio gives only 0 [SQL]

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to calculate the ratio of returning customers vs. total customers

Sample table

```
customer_id   is_returning_customer 
934           1
294           0
042           0
194           1
839           1
```

Using the following code below

```
select count(distinct customer_id) as n_customers, 
  count(
    distinct (
      CASE
        WHEN is_returning_customer = 1 THEN customer_id
      END)) as n_returning_customers
from table
```

I get the following output:

```
n_customers  n_returning_customers
5            3
```

But when using this code to calculate the ratio of returning customers - I get as a result 0

```
select
  cast(
    count(
      distinct (
        CASE
          WHEN is_returning_customer = 1 THEN customer_id
        END
      )
    ) / count(distinct customer_id) as DECIMAL(9, 5)
  ) as returning_customer_ratio
from table
```

Result

```
returning_customer_ratio
0
```

Comment: cast _before_ dividing. (Now you do cast(3 / 5 = 0 as ...)

Comment: if I cast before dividing I get the following error: cannot cast bigint to decimal

Comment: See https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-division-operator/ for more details

Comment: Is distinct necessary in your example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `avg` aggregate function:

```
select avg(is_returning_customer) as returning_customer_ratio
from (
    select customer_id, max(is_returning_customer) as is_returning_customer
    from table_name
    group by customer_id
) t;
```